# Initializing objects

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Diference between [NSMutableArray array] vs [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423211/diference-between-nsmutablearray-array-vs-nsmutablearray-alloc-init)

Using Objective-C/Cocoa, what's the difference between:

```
NSMutableData *myData = [NSMutableData data];
NSMutableString *myString = [NSMutableString string];
```

and

```
NSMutableData *myData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSMutableString *myString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

They seem to have the same end result as far as I can tell?

Comment: Have a look at ["Object Creation"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ObjectCreation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH39-SW1) in the Cocoa Core Competencies Guide.

Comment: look @ the apple memory guide - important read.  alloc, copy, mutableCopy means you own it and you need to release.  Anything else (by convention) calls autorelease and will get released on next cycle ...

Comment: if you need to hold onto something that's autoreleased outside of the scope of the function that you got it, then you should retain it and then release later.

Answer (score -1):

[NSMutableData data] is referred to as a helper, check this post, [Helper functions in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367724/helper-functions-in-cocoa)

Helpers generally take care of the memory management for your, can also be used to return singletons.

[[NSMutableData] alloc] init], you are responsible for memory management.

Although if you are using ARC you don't have to release your objects, it does it for you.

Comment: The post you linked to doesn't have anything to do with this. These methods are "convenience constructors".